# How to change the axis interval in asp.net chart

Tags: asp.net, charts

How do I reduce the interval between the x-axis value?. Please see below picture

[image]

I used

```
chart.ChartAreas["chart1"].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
chart.ChartAreas["chart1"].AxisX.Maximum = 100;
chart.ChartAreas["chart1"].AxisX.Interval = 10;
```

And it doesn't work well. Maybe because it is a string value?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `interval type` before setting values to it

Try this:

```
chartCheck.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = Your type here;
```

Comment: Actual type is a string how to show that exactly..with the intervals difference.